# HTTPS sites not working in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis

I'm facing an issue with our sites using SSL not working.

We have a URL rewrite rule setup to automatically redirect site visitors from http to https. However, this does not seem to be causing any issues as if I disable the rule and then go to http, the site works. If I go to https explicitly with the rule disabled, it will not work. So it does appear to be SSL causing the issue.

We are using a wildcard cert with multiple sites all sharing an IP managed via SSL Host Headers. This could be the cause of the issue but I'm not sure.

Browsing to the HTTPS site shows "This page can't be displayed" and no further useful information.

I'm trying to look through the IIS logs for useful information now, will update this if I come across anything in the mean time.

Comment: It often helps to perform tests with static pages in such cases: just place a trivial HTML file in the root of your web site and see if it works. Otherwise, the simples path is often to use packet sniffer and chec at what level the connection fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is documented anywhere but it appears that somebody removed the SSL binding from one of our sites on this server which broke the wildcard SSL binding for all sites as a result.

I added this back to the site in question and then all of the sites started working once again.